# Django posting nested JSON inside n number of tables

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am having trouble posting nested fields to database. All i want to do is to add lender and borrower to different tables in database. Loan JSON post format:

```
{
    "lender": {
        "email": "lender@hotmail.com"
    },
    "borrower": {
        "email": "borrower@gmail.com"
    },
    "amount": 4
}
```

This post must add lender to Lender table and borrower to Borrower table and Loan to loan table.

My view:

```
class LenderLoanAddAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = lenderloan_serializers.AddLenderLoanSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        lender = self.kwargs['lender']
        return Loan.objects.filter(lender=lender).order_by('-id')
```

My serialiser:

```
class AddLenderLoanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lender = LenderSerializer(many=False)
    borrower = BorrowerSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:

        model = Loan
        fields = ('lender','borrower', 'amount',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        lender = Lender(
            email = validated_data['lender']
        )
        borrower = Borrower(
            email = validated_data['borrower']
        )
        lender.save()
        borrower.save()

        return lender
```

I think i must implement create method in another way. Unfortunately i don't know how. Can you please help me with this nested serializer? I really need to go on but i am stuck with this problem.